# Why my class library is looking for specific version of the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces?

Tags: c#, redis, class-library

I have a class library in .NetFramework 4.8 for Redis which has nuget package: `stackexchange.redis 2.1.58`. This is the website([Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/2.1.58#dependencies-body-tab)) which clearly states that library is dependent on `Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces 1.1.1 or greater`. Now when I am using ASP.NET web API containing the following in web.config but doesn't have Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces installed:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This is the code of my class library

```
public static void SetRecord(string recordId, string data, int minute = 30)
        {
            var redisConnection = Common.RedisCacheServiceClient();
            IDatabase dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();

            var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minute);
            dbConnection.StringSet(recordId, data, timeSpan);

        }
```

The class library has `Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces 1.1.1` installed and `stackexchange.redis 2.1.58` but when the program hits `IDatabase dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();` then it throws the following error:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"}

When I see the other class library of the project they also contain the same version of Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces 1.1.1 and has the following assembly identity in their app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

What I am confused about is why API contains the reference for Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces when the library is not even installed? When other class library are working fine with Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 1.1.1 and wrong reference to Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces in app.config then why my project is failing when I am doing the same? Lastly, Why it is the error only states the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 6.0.0 missing, why is it even looking for it and not Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 1.1.1?

Comment: That's the way assembly redirects work. Whenever a part of the code needs Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces in a version up to 6.0.0.0 (also also 1.1.1), .NET will try to load version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Thank you @KlausGütter it was very helpful. I read about assembly redirects. How can i get assembly versions in nuget package?